# After updating xcode to xcode 7, I am getting a bunch of errors, anyway to not require update to new syntax?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Im getting a bunch of errors after updating xcode. Am I required to update to swift 2 and revise my code or can I somehow edit preferences so it usues swift 1? Will there be issues when I submit the app?

Answer (score 1):

> can I somehow edit preferences so it usues swift 1?

To use your existing Swift1 code with Xcode7, you have to convert it to Swift2.

> I am getting a bunch of errors, anyway to not require update to new
>   syntax?

To get rid of these error, you can make use of Xcode7 tool, which will automatically convert your Swift1 to Swift2.

[image]

Comment: that doesn't help at all. the errors come after i converted to swift 2. u dont even have to goto edit -> convert, it prompts you after opening a xcode project on xcode7.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submit/):

> Xcode 7 requires Swift 2. If your app uses Swift 1.2, you can use the Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax menu item in Xcode 7 to convert your code to Swift 2.

That means you must have to update your syntax for 2.0.